# Agregar a Transifex el texto de alerta de la etiqueta [untagged] que indica que no está permitida

Tags: bug, estado-completado, etiquetas

Al intentar crear una pregunta con la etiqueta [untagged](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged) se muestra la siguiente alerta

[image]

> La etiqueta "untagged" no está permitida.
>
> This tag is for use by the system for questions that have had all other tags removed. Please use [a real tag](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags) instead.

Como ven la segunda parte está en inglés y dicho texto no se encuentra en Transifex.

Me imagino que este es uno de los casos "límites" y tal vez más que agregarlo a Transifex habría que hacer otra cosa, pero bueno, ya nos contarán "qué onda".

Sugerencia de traducción

> Esta etiqueta es de uso exclusivo del sistema para preguntas cuyas otras etiquetas han sido eliminadas. Por favor, en su lugar usa [una etiqueta válida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags).

Nota al margen: El texto de la ayuda del panel derecho (sólo busqué `A tag is a keyword`) si está pero sin traducir.

[image]

> Cómo etiquetar
>
> A tag is a keyword or label that categorizes your question with other,
>   similar questions. Choose one or more (up to 5) tags that will help
>   answerers to find and interpret your question.
>
> ► complete the sentence: my question is about...
>
> ► use tags that describe things or concepts that are essential, not
>   incidental to your question
>
> ► favor using existing popular tags
>
> ► read the descriptions that appear below the tag
>
> If your question is primarily about a topic for which you can't find a
>   tag:
>
> ► combine multiple words into single-words with hyphens (e.g.
>   android-studio), up to a maximum of 35 characters
>
> ► creating new tags is a privilege; if you can't yet create a tag you
>   need, then post this question without it, then ask the community to
>   create it for you

Comment: este texto no está en transifex sino en la base de datos. Si me dan una traducción lo arreglo. Los textos de ayuda para las etiquetas en la lista negra los tengo que agregar manualmente

Comment: Esta etiqueta es de uso exclusivo del sistema para preguntas cuyas otras etiquetas han sido removidas. Por favor en su lugar usa una  etiqueta válida.

Comment: ¡Bien visto! Cambié _remover_ por _eliminar_, pues al menos en España _remover_ no se usa. ¿Se entiende bien así?

Comment: Respecto la parte _El texto de la ayuda del panel derecho (sólo busqué A tag is a keyword) si está pero sin traducir_, sugiero añadir una pregunta diferente, para poder compartimentar las peticiones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listo! quedó traducido el texto tanto en SOes como en meta. Al igual que fedorqui, coincido en que lo mejor sería traducir ese texto en Transifex.

Eliminé [agregar-a-transifex](/questions/tagged/agregar-a-transifex) porque no es posible agregar las cadenas de los mensajes de error a transifex.